# EF6 Code First - AllowHtml causes database field to be nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

EF6.1.2, ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 environment

I have to admit, at first I thought I was going mad.  I noticed one of our database fields had become nullable, when I hadn't expected it to, following a call to update-database.  I asked around the team, and no-one had knowingly changed the field's nullability.

It took me a while to discover the cause, but it looks like it came down to a developer adding the ASP.NET MVC attribute `[AllowHtml]` to the entity property, overriding existing `[Required]` attributes.  I had to verify this a few times by finding other examples, checking that they too were nullable, and removing the `[AllowHtml]` to check whether this triggered a change from Nullable to Non-Nullable fields.

I've checked to ensure no-one has added any weird new conventions etc. to the application.  It doesn't appear to be anything custom.

Has anyone else seen this, and does anyone know whether we can disable this in some way?  I'm in the process of isolating the entities from MVC-specific stuff like this, but it's going to take a while to complete, and now I know about this, I'm keen to sort the existing instances.

Comment: you can try rolling back the migrations to the point before the migration that caused the issue, generate a new migration, and manually add a `nullable: false` to the column/property in question. don't see any reason that shouldn't work but I've not tested it personally

Comment: Unfortunately we use automatic migrations, so I'd have to completely re-train the team to use explicit migrations.  I'm wondering whether I can use the model builder extension points to counter this somehow, but ideally I'd like to get to the bottom of the cause, as it's entirely possible there are other attributes and other unintended schema changes going on.

Comment: Kerieks' answer (and Genolkari's comment on it) here will provide some more details which may help with understanding however I'm not sure of a solution as of right now for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601498/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-thinks-there-is-a-change-that-shouldnt-b?noredirect=1&lq=1 ...an alternative would be to ditch the `[AllowHtml]` attribute and look into other solutions to safely store and render the stored html on the page. be careful doing so though :)